# How to render django model instances in particular order using django templates?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I have for div in my html with their id each like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="myclass" id="id1"></div>
  <div class="myclass" id="id2"></div>
  <div class="myclass" id="id3"></div>
  <div class="myclass" id="id4"></div>
</div>
```

Now how can I render the instance of the model in the order specified below ?

first instance in first div of the row

second instance in second div of the row

third instance in third div of the row

fourth instance in fourth div of the row

and fifth instance in first div of the row so one and so forth.

Any help would be appreciate even if it is using javascript hope it would be lot more simpler there.

Comment: So exactly what do you pass to the template. Can you share the relevant view?

Comment: I pass it all the instances of the model by model.objects.all () and passing it to the context in order to access it into the template

Answer (score 0):

In the view you can "prepare" the data by using:

```
def my_view(request):
    d = 4  # items per row
    items = list(MyModel.objects.all())
    items = [items[i:i+d] for i in range(0, len(items), d)]
    return render(request, 'name-of-template.html', {'items': items})
```

Then we can enumerate over the sublists, and for each sublist, can enumerate over the items in that sublist, so:

```
{% for sublist in items %}
    <div class="row">
    {% for item in sublist %}
        <div class="myclass">{{ item }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here the `queryset` is the `model.objects.all()` you pass to the template render engine.

Comment: I did enumerate over the items but it renders a number of divs equal to the len of the number of instances of the model

Comment: @PapisDiallo: you should slice in the view, so the view looks like `queryset = MyModel.objects.all()[:5]`.

Comment: Then I won't be able to render all the instances of the model and that's what I want. Maybe the question was not really clear. In the first div I want the first, fifth, nineth instance and in the second I want the second, sixth, tenth items and so on

Comment: @PapisDiallo: so you want to use rows with five elements?

Comment: No just four but the elements should be display like I precised in the question. the first element in the database in the first div, the second element in the second div the third element in the third div the fourth element in the fourth div now the fifth element should go to first div and the sixth one the second div and all the other elements will follow this logic

Comment: @PapisDiallo: then you need to "prepare" the data in the view, see edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235849/discussion-between-papis-diallo-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: This is slightly different from what but here is a schema

Comment: We are rendering 4 elements per row I want one row with four div.

Comment: @PapisDiallo: exactly what is not working with the given solution? You create sublists in the view, and then render these in the template with four items per row.

Comment: Exactly it is working as you said but I want only one row with four divs in it not a particular number of instance per row. See logic of the other answer is good but I can't render since django doesn't allow rendering functions with parameter and one of them is dynamic. I tried template tags but not working.

Answer (score 0):

in your html file:

```
<!-- some code -->

<div class="row">
    {% for div_id in range(4) %}
    <div class="myclass" id="id{{ div_id + 1 }}">
        {% for instance in chosenInstances(instances, div_id + 1) %}
        {{ instance }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<!-- some code -->
```

and in python:

```
def chosenInstances(instances, div_id):
    return [instance for index, instance in enumerate(instances) if (index % 4 + 1) == div_id]

render_template("htmlfile.html", chosenInstances=chosenInstances)
```

Comment: You answer is correct. But the issue is django template does not accept passing functions with arguments and this function does not only contain arguments but the second one is also dynamic. I was thinking about using filters but I won't be dynamic at all.

Comment: I missmatched Django with Jinja2 ‍♂️

Comment: I am still trying to fix by combining the 2 answers.